# Trigger function not working properly on multiple inserts in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, postgis

So basically I've got table1 that people do regular inserts, and table2 that needs to get updated based on what people insert on table1

table1 has
    id integer
    type text
    ref text
    geom polygon geometry

table2 has
    idb integer
    status integer
    ref text
    geom point geometry

Users can sometimes do bulk inserts into table1. My trigger function to update table2 is

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table2update()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

BEGIN
update table2 a set status = 50, ref =  new."ref"
where new.type = 'POLE' and new."ref" is not null and st_contains(new.geom,a.geom);
RETURN new;
END;

$function$
;
```

trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER derp BEFORE INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE table2update();
```

People do their inserts on a software called QGIS but it looks like the following

```
insert into table1(type,ref,geom)
values('POLE', 'derp','geom'),
('not pole', null, 'geom')
```

Expected behaviour, all the rows in table2 contained by the polygons in table1 will have the ref updated, as well as the status, but only where the type of inserts in table1 are 'POLE'

Actual behaviour, all the rows get updated with the status, but the type is completely ignored - in other words, the ref stays null but the status changes. When a user pastes a single row of type 'POLE', it works as intended however I do not want to encourage people not inputting all the data

How to fix the code?

Comment: You don't show the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement, and it would help to see the triggering SQL statement.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe added the trigger

Comment: You have a consistency issue. The trigger function you posted, planning.new_boundary(), is NOT the function you are calling, table2update(). Please post the trigger function corresponding to the  procedure executed by trigger.

Comment: @Belayer sorry. fixed now

Comment: Thanks. So how does the `INSERT` look, and what *exactly* happens? Your verbal description is not clear enough for me.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe added more explanation

Comment: It is impossible that the trigger updates `status` in `table2`, but not `ref`. Perhaps the values in `NEW` are different from what you think. Sprinkle the code with `RAISE NOTICE` that output the actual values of the variables to debug this.